Error found in books?
I was reading books called Sequences and Series: An Introduction to Mathematical Analysis by Malcolm R.Adams. There is a confusion arise when the author talk about how to apply limit comparison test. The author wants to apply limit comparison test on this $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^2}$ series so he make slight modification to make a "larger" sequence. This is how he construct the "larger" sequence: $$\\$$
"Let $b_1=1$ and for all natural number n $\ge$ 2 we have $b_n={1\over(n-1)n}$" $$\\$$
Then he said that: "since $(n-1)$ $\lt n$ we have $\color{red}{\mathbf {b_n={1\over(n-1)n}\lt{1\over n^2}}}$" $$\\$$
Is this typo or I have not get what author try to do? Thanks for the help!

Seems like an error. Hopefully it’s not too hard to fix the proof.

Yes, just reverse the inequality symbol can make the proof work, thank you !
@littleO

Yes, it is an error. The proof most probably wants to use a telescoping series, and I think just flipping the sign
$$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}<\frac1{n^2}$$
should fix it. Let me know if this works.

Yes, just reserve the symbol makes the proof works, thank you !
@ultralegend5385
